# Amazon Market Place item price increases after I place it in my shopping cart — can vendors tell?

Tags: amazon

I placed an item from Amazon Market Place (i.e. 3rd party vendors selling on Amazon) in my shopping cart.  It was a used item and rare enough to cost significantly more than when it was new.  24 hours after I placed it in my shopping cart, the vendor increased the price by 20%.

Can the vendor tell that the item was in my shopping cart?